# sort tables bookmark using correct date format

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to write a bookmarklet utility that will sort tables shown in the browser.
I use this...

```
javascript:function toArray (c){var a, k;a=new Array;for (k=0; k<c.length; ++k)a[k]=c[k];return a;}function insAtTop(par,child){if(par.childNodes.length) par.insertBefore(child, par.childNodes[0]);else par.appendChild(child);}function countCols(tab){var nCols, i;nCols=0;for(i=0;i<tab.rows.length;++i)if(tab.rows[i].cells.length>nCols)nCols=tab.rows[i].cells.length;return nCols;}function makeHeaderLink(tableNo, colNo, ord){var link;link=document.createElement('a');link.href='javascript:sortTable('+tableNo+','+colNo+','+ord+');';link.appendChild(document.createTextNode((ord>0)?%27a%27:%27d%27));return link;}function makeHeader(tableNo,nCols){var header, headerCell, i;header=document.createElement(%27tr%27);for(i=0;i<nCols;++i){headerCell=document.createElement(%27td%27);headerCell.appendChild(makeHeaderLink(tableNo,i,1));headerCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(%27/%27));headerCell.appendChild(makeHeaderLink(tableNo,i,-1));header.appendChild(headerCell);}return header;}g_tables=toArray(document.getElementsByTagName(%27table%27));if(!g_tables.length) alert(%27This page does not contain any tables.%27);(function(){var j, thead;for(j=0;j<g_tables.length;++j){thead=g_tables[j].createTHead();insAtTop(thead, makeHeader(j,countCols(g_tables[j])))}}) ();function compareRows(a,b){if(a.sortKey==b.sortKey)return 0;return (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) ? g_order : -g_order;}function sortTable(tableNo, colNo, ord){var table, rows, nR, bs, i, j, temp;g_order=ord;g_colNo=colNo;table=g_tables[tableNo];rows=new Array();nR=0;bs=table.tBodies;for(i=0; i<bs.length; ++i)for(j=0; j<bs[i].rows.length; ++j){rows[nR]=bs[i].rows[j];temp=rows[nR].cells[g_colNo];if(temp) rows[nR].sortKey=temp.innerHTML;else rows[nR].sortKey=%27%27;++nR;}rows.sort(compareRows);for (i=0; i < rows.length; ++i)insAtTop(table.tBodies[0], rows[i]);}
```

and it works as expected.
The only time it fails is when the columns contain dates like...

```
15 December 2021 1:20 AM UTC+5:30
21 August 2020 4:13 AM UTC+5:30
29 May 2021 2:04 AM UTC+5:30
```

As you can see it has sorted based on 15<21<29 but it should be 21<29<15

Is it possible to write a bookmarket utility for this?

Comment: You should first parse the dates into the **ISO8601** date format, then sort them.